# Ruby mongo - array map add another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `MongoDB` model like:

```
Posts: id, category, data[title, description, slug..]
```

I was adding my data to `my_array` but now I need to add `category` field

```
my_array = []

my_array[:posts] = Posts.all.to_a.map { |p| p.data }
```

How can I merge them to see this result?

```
my_array: {[ category1, title1, description1, slug1], [ category2, title2, description2, slug2]}
```

So, I want to push the category field into the same array, but I don't know how to change this query

```
 my_array[:posts] = Posts.all.to_a.map { |p| p.data }
```

Comment: can you please explain what do you want to merge? do you want to merge the multiple arrays into one big array with all the fields?

Comment: no, I want to add the category field to my_array. But category and data array should be same level..

Comment: I can do my_array[:posts] = Posts.all.to_a.map { |p| p } and get all posts , but if i do so, data and category won't be in same level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to merge the category to the hash you will need to get the data then merge a category key with the category

```rb
my_array[:posts] = Posts.all.to_a.map { |p| p.data.merge(category: p.category) }
```

Comment: I've tried it but could not get the category field..

Comment: can you post what you actually got out of one record and post the record's columns as well?

Comment: Actually i get it into array but its like: [{'title' => 'a' , 'descrition'=> 'a'}, BSON::ObjectId('60715018bee8403af3a10d11')  ]

Comment: if you check my answer, category_id is a bson object. But it's not on same level with other data. It's not in same curly brackets..

Comment: are you able to call `.str` on the `BSON::ObjectId('60715018bee8403af3a10d11')` and get the value back?

Comment: no, in view when I call each, I can get the title with the post[:title] but how can I get category..

Comment: `my_array[:posts] = Posts.all.to_a.map { |p| [p.data, :category => p.category].flatten }` not i can get the category, but still they are not in same curly bracket

Comment: updated the answer, le me know if it works